# Simplifying Trace of a Matrix Expression ${\rm Tr} \left( (I- D^{-1} BA^2) B (I- D^{-1} BA^2)^T \right)$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, trace

Let $B$ be a symmetric invertible matrix  and let $A$ be a diagonal matrix with non-zero entries on the main diagonal.

I am trying to simplify the following expression 
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr} \left( (I- D^{-1} BA^2) B (I- D^{-1} BA^2)^T \right)
\end{align}
where $D=I+ ABA$

**Case that I did:**

In the one dimensional case we get 
\begin{align}
\frac{B}{(1+BA^2)^2}.
\end{align}

Also in the case that $A = a I$ (all diagonal elements are the same) we get

\begin{align}
(I- D^{-1} BA^2) B (I- D^{-1} BA^2)^T = (I+ BA^2)^{-1} B (I+ BA^2)^{-1}
\end{align} 
and therefore the trace becomes
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr} \left( (I- D^{-1} BA^2) B (I- D^{-1} BA^2)^T \right)= {\rm Tr} \left( (1+ABA)^{-1} B(1+ABA)^{-1} \right)= {\rm Tr} \left(  B(1+ABA)^{-2} \right).
\end{align}

My **question** is what can we say about a more general diagonal $A$? Can we show also that 
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr} \left( (I- D^{-1} BA^2) B (I- D^{-1} BA^2)^T \right)= {\rm Tr} \left( (1+ABA)^{-1} B(1+ABA)^{-1} \right)= {\rm Tr} \left(  B(1+ABA)^{-2} \right)
\end{align}

Note that another way to look at this problem is to look through the norm operator
\begin{align}
\| I- D^{-1} BA^2 \|
\end{align}

I wounder if there is a software that can take care of this simplification.

Comment: Your calculation when $n=1$ is false.

Comment: @loupblanc thanks. you are right there was a typo. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily checked (e.g., using Matlab for some $A$ with non-equal entries) that when $A$ has different diagonal elements the relation that you mention does not hold in general, i.e., in general
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Tr}((I-D^{-1}BA^2)B(I-D^{-1}BA^2)^T)\neq \mathrm{Tr}(B(I+ABA)^{-2}).
\end{equation}

You can however play around a bit with that expression by considering the trace is not affected by circular shifts in its matrices. Furthermore, since $D$ is also symmetric from its structure $$(I+ABA)^T=I+A^TB^TA^T = I+ABA,$$ so you may write
\begin{equation}
(I-D^{-1}BA^2)^T=I-A^2BD^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Then you can circularly shift the previous expression and reach
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Tr}((I-D^{-1}BA^2)B(I-D^{-1}BA^2)^T)=\mathrm{Tr}((I-2D^{-1}BA^2+A^2BD^{-2}BA^2)B),
\end{equation}
where I have also considered that the trace of the sum is the sum of traces, so you may circularly shift each sum element independently. Maybe a more compact expression is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Tr}((I-D^{-1}BA^2)B(I-D^{-1}BA^2)^T)=\mathrm{Tr}(B+BA^2BD^{-1}(D^{-1}BA^2-2I)).
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, I can't get much further since the product $BD^{-1}$ (or the converse) cannot be easily reduced since having $A$ with different diagonal entries is messing up the eigenspace of $B$, i.e., you cannot diagonalize $I+ABA$, or even $ABA$ with the same orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes $B$ unless $A$ has equal entries.